# Extracting Path Head in Akka Directives

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am using [akka directives](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.2/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/by-trait.html) to match a particular path pattern:

```
/item/quantity
```

Examples would be

```
/apples/100
/bananas/200
```

The possible items (e.g. "apples", "bananas", ...) is not known in advance, therefore hard-coding the items using `path` is not an option.

However, I can't find a PathMatcher that extracts the head of the path.  I'm looking for something of the form

```
val route = 
  get {
    path(PathHeadAsString) { item : String =>
      path(IntNumber) { qty : Int =>
        complete(s"item: $item quantity: $qty")
      } ~ complete("no quantity specified")
    } ~ complete("no item specified")
  }
```

Where

```
Get("/apples/100") ~> route ~> check {
  responseAs[String] shouldEqual "item: apples quantity: 100"
}
```

**Is there a way to extract the first segment of the path?**

The `path(segment)` matcher will not match if the quantity is in the path.

I obviously could use `path(segments)` to get a `List[String]` of the path elements but I would then have to extract the list head and list tail manually which seems inelegant.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Just as a side note, you may be fully aware: you'll probably want appropriate directives to match the http methods: _get_, _post_, _put_, etc..

Comment: @RichardSitze I updated my example code accordingly.  Thank you for the side note.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can [compose PathMatchers with modifiers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.2/scala/http/routing-dsl/path-matchers.html#Modifiers) thus

```
path(Segment / IntNumber) { case (item, qty) =>
  complete(s"item: $item quantity: $qty")
}
```

OR if you need the full break-out use `pathPrefix`:

```
val route = 
pathPrefix(Segment) { item : String =>
  path(IntNumber) { qty : Int =>
    complete(s"item: $item quantity: $qty")
  } ~
  pathEnd { complete("no quantity specified") } ~
  complete("something else going on here")
} ~
complete("no item specified")
```

(Note the additional `pathEnd` directive there; even with that I wouldn't say the patterns matched represent all possible situations.)

From [akka routing directives](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.2/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/alphabetically.html):

- the `pathPrefix` directive "*Applies the given PathMatcher to a prefix of the remaining unmatched path after consuming a leading slash.*"
- the `path` directive "*Applies the given PathMatcher to the remaining unmatched path after consuming a leading slash.*"
- the `pathEnd` directive "*Only passes on the request to its inner route if the request path has been matched completely.*"

From [akka path-matchers](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/path-matchers.html), the `Segment` path matcher "*Matches if the unmatched path starts with a path segment (i.e. not a slash). If so the path segment is extracted as a String instance.*"

Comment: Why you do `case (item, qty) => ...`, not just `(item, qty) => ...`? Why it has to be a partial function?

Comment: @AntonK my assumption (i.e. guess) is that _Route_ is determining if a _pathMatcher_ matches or not by virtue of being able to ask the partial function if it is  _isDefinedAt_ the given param(s).